# Pyspark - Looking to apply SQL queries to pyspark dataframes

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

Disclaimer: I'm very new to pyspark and this question might not be appropriate.

I've seen the following code online:

```
# Get the id, age where age = 22 in SQL
spark.sql("select id, age from swimmers where age = 22").show()
```

Now, I've tried to pivot using pyspark with the following code:

```
complete_dataset.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
temp = spark.sql("SELECT core_id from df")
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;'
```

I figured this would be straightforward but I can't seem to find the solution. Is this posible to do in pyspark?

NOTE: I am on an EMR Cluster using a Pyspark notebook.

Comment: how are you creating a sparkSession & version of spark? not sure whether it is related but still wanted to know

Comment: have you enabled hive support? check `enableHiveSupport()` is there while creating sparksession

Comment: @SomeshwarKale: I am on an EMR Cluster. I am using a Pyspark notebook. I'm not explicitly creating a sparkSession.

Comment: check the value for `spark.sql.catalogImplementation` property from sparkSession

Comment: @SomeshwarKale I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'catalogImplementation'`. I'm very new to spark/pyspark so I may be missing something. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: check this link- https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-SparkSession.html

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark you can read MySQL table (assuming that you are using MySQL) and create dataframe.

```
    jdbc_url = 'jdbc:mysql://{}:{}@{}/{}?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL'.format(
    'usrname',
    'password',
    'host',
    'db',
)

    table_df = sql_ctx.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table='table_name').select("column_name1", "column_name2")
```

Where `table_df` is the dataframe. The you can do required operations on dataframe like filter etc.

```
table_df.filter(table_df.column1 == 'abc').show()
```